# What does kets $|0\rangle$ or $|1\rangle$ exactly mean in linear algebra?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, vectors, linear-algebra, quantum-states

In a textbook of quantum mechanics, the author frequently makes use of notations like $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. What I am curious about is their dimensions. How can you have a matrix representation of these vectors if you don't know their dimensions?

For instance, one of the questions in the book is as follows:

> Let $|\Psi\rangle = \frac{(|0\rangle+|1\rangle)}{\sqrt{2}}$. Write out
>   $|\Psi\rangle^{\otimes2}$ and $|\Psi\rangle^{\otimes3}$ explicitly using the
>   Kronecker product.

You can't use the Kronecker product if you don't know the matrix representation, right? 
Then how do I answer this question?

Comment: What happens if you start from the 2-dimensional space defined by these two orthogonal vectors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A ket vector is a vector in the Hilbert space of your quantum system.  In your specific case
\begin{align}
\vert 0\rangle \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{c} 1\\ 0\end{array}\right)\, ,\qquad 
\vert 1\rangle \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{c} 0\\ 1\end{array}\right)\, . 
\end{align}

You can take the direct product of two vectors
\begin{align}
\vert \psi_1\rangle \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{c} a_1\\ b_1\end{array}\right)\, ,\qquad 
\vert \psi_2\rangle \mapsto \left(\begin{array}{c} a_2\\ b_2\end{array}\right)\, . 
\end{align}
so that 
\begin{align}
\vert \psi_1\rangle\otimes \vert \psi_2\rangle \mapsto
\left(\begin{array}{c} a_1\\ b_1\end{array}\right)\otimes \left(\begin{array}{c} a_2\\ b_2\end{array}\right) 
=\left(\begin{array}{c}a_1a_2\\ a_1b_2\\ b_1a_2\\ b_2a_2\end{array}\right)\, .
\end{align}
The particular case 
$$
\vert\psi\rangle^{\otimes p}=\vert\psi\rangle\otimes\vert\psi\rangle\otimes
\dots \vert\psi\rangle\, ,\qquad  \hbox{with }p\hbox{ products of} \vert\psi\rangle.
$$

Answer (score 0):

*Bra* and *ket* are a symbolic representation of states, which can be either functions, or vectors of some other objects, depending on the representation. What is truly meaningful is the matrix elements. For example, we can have:
$$|\psi\rangle = \psi(x), |\phi\rangle = \phi(x),\\
\langle\phi|\hat{O}|\psi\rangle = \int dx \phi^*(x)\hat{O}\psi(x).$$
We could also also have
$$|\uparrow\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix},
|\downarrow\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\end{pmatrix},\\
\langle\downarrow|\hat{O}|\uparrow\rangle =  \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}O_{11}&O_{12}\\O_{21}&O_{22}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\end{pmatrix},$$
or 
$$|+1\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix},
|-1\rangle = \begin{pmatrix} 0\\0\\1\end{pmatrix},\\
\langle -1|\hat{O}|1\rangle =  \begin{pmatrix} 0&0&1\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}O_{11}&O_{12}&O_{13}\\O_{21}&O_{22}&O_{23}\\O_{31}&O_{32}&O_{33}\end{pmatrix}\cdot \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

As you see this is a very flexible notation, but its exact meaning depends on the context.

**Remark**
It was pointed out in the comments that more mathematically correct is writing $\psi(x)=\langle x|\psi\rangle$. This is however not a meaningful distinction: first of all, because one could also identify $|x\rangle =\delta (x-y)$, and secondly because the very same complain could (and should!) be made in respect to my other examples. Bras and kets are introduced for **performing the mathematical manipulations independently from the basis**, or, as it was done in my answer, with the basis of your choice.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106888/discussion-on-answer-by-vadim-what-does-kets-0-rangle-or-1-rangle-exactly).

Comment: Your remark isn't fully true either. Technically you would have $\langle y|x\rangle=\delta(x-y)$, where $|x\rangle$ and $|y\rangle$ are two position eigenstates. $\delta(x-y)$ are position eigenfunctions in the position basis. $|x\rangle$ is just an abstract notion of a position eigenstate. That is why they are not equal (same as the previous issue of $|\psi\rangle=\psi(x)$).