# $(α|0⟩ + β|1⟩)|0⟩$ in matrix/vector form

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, notation

I am currently working through superdense coding with bell states and have a question regarding this value:

$$(α|0⟩ \ + \ β|1⟩) \ |0⟩$$

I understand that $α|0⟩ \  + \  β|1⟩$ can be represented in vector format as $(α \ \  β)$ (vertically)

However, I'm not sure how to apply the outer $|0⟩$ ket? Would it be $(α \ \ β)×(1 \ \  0)$ which would give $α$?

Comment: You're looking for the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). See eg [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/544859/291677)

Answer (score 3):

This operation is what's called the tensor product. More formally it is denoted by
$$|\psi\rangle\otimes|\phi\rangle$$
but often the $\otimes$ is left out. When calculated numerically it is called the Kronecker product which can be calculated as follows for a 2 state system
$$\pmatrix{a\\b}\otimes\pmatrix{c\\d}=\pmatrix{ac\\ad\\bc\\bd}.$$
See also the [wiki page on the Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) for a more general computation. To get a little more intuition you can calculate all the combinations of $\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}\otimes\{|0\rangle,|1\rangle\}$ where $|0\rangle=\pmatrix{1\\0}$ and $|1\rangle=\pmatrix{0\\1}$. When you do this you will see that the result is a unit vector with the $1$ at all 4 different positions: the result gives all basis vectors of a 4 state system.

Edit: It is also distrubitive so $$\big(|\alpha\rangle+|\beta\rangle\big)\otimes|\gamma\rangle=|\alpha\rangle\otimes|\gamma\rangle+|\beta\rangle\otimes|\gamma\rangle\\
|\alpha\rangle\otimes\big(|\beta\rangle)+|\gamma\rangle\big)=|\alpha\rangle\otimes|\beta\rangle+|\alpha\rangle\otimes|\gamma\rangle$$
and this should allow you to calculate the tensor product product in question.

Comment: This is great, thank you. I get a 4x1 matrix which equals (1 0 1 0) (apologies for not knowing how to format this correctly.)

Comment: @Hemmed You should get $\pmatrix{\alpha&0&\beta&0}^T$ so you have the right shape but I don't know what happened to your $\alpha,\beta$. If you want to know how to format correctly check out https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/ . To type a ket you can use | and \rangle. and $\otimes$ is \otimes.

Comment: Sorry - I was silly and dropped them! I do get to your answer. Apologies for the confusion.